# [[maybe_unused]] on label defined but not used

Tags: c++, goto, suppress-warnings

[[[maybe_unused]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) seems that does not apply to `goto` labels, but on g++ `[[maybe_unused]]` works and suppress warning.

What the standard says? Can I assume that this happens to other compilers too? (if standard does not say this).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template<uint32_t C>
struct Fixed
{
    static constexpr uint32_t Components = C;
    constexpr uint32_t components() const { return Components; }
};
struct Variable
{
    static constexpr uint32_t Components = 0;
    uint32_t c = 3;
    uint32_t components() const { return c; }
};

template<typename T>
void function(T &&t)
{
    if constexpr (T::Components <= 1)
    {
        if constexpr (!T::Components) if (t.components() != 1) goto con;
        cout << "1 component, fixed or not\n";
        goto fin;
    }
[[maybe_unused]] con:     // here it is!
cout << "many components, fixed or not\n";
fin:
cout << "final jobs\n";
}


int main()
{
    function(Fixed<1>{});
    function(Variable{});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? With [gcc 10.1.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yEavry8zEgYG4Ccf) the comment doesn't work and a warning appears.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I remove the comment.

Comment: There's also `std::ignore`

Answer (score 2):

The [standard states](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.attr.unused#2):

> [maybe-unused] may be applied to the declaration of a class, a typedef-name, a variable, a non-static data member, a function, an enumeration, or an enumerator.

A goto label is not on that list, so it may not have this attribute applied.